# saving/reading csv file from/to database in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to save a csv file to a SQL Server Database table using C#?

Do need to convert the csv file to Binary format in order to do this?

Is there any other way, like saving it in text format(csv is a basically a txt file)?

I'd appreciate it if you could provide some example code.

Comment: CSV file can be directly imported on SQL Server without using C#. [See This Link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

Comment: If you really want to import using C#, [here's a project from CodeProject: C# - (CSV Import Export)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export)

Comment: Can you please clarify if you explicitly don't want to break the CSV into multiple data fields?  Depending on your scenario, it might be better to do this rather than keeping a copy of the entire file in the database.   But on the other hand, if you just need a copy of the file, the database might not be the best place for it - rather, perhaps your DB could just contain a file-path to the location of the file stored on a filesystem somewhere.

Comment: I dont want to break the csv file. And I want to save the entire file in one record because there might be hundreds of files coming from different users.

Comment: Do you need to be able to query against the values in the CSV, or just extract the CSV "on demand" based on selection of other fields from your table?  If so, then you could encode it or zip it or whatever, before importing it.  But again, is the DB the best place for the file itself, rather than just a reference to the file, if you're not performing DB-like operations on the file as a whole, or on its contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV files are just text. You can create a table that has an nvarchar(max) column and store your CSV files in there.

Comment: But I want to save the whole file in one single record. Can you provide some code.

Comment: I don't understand. You can insert your entire CSV file into a single column of type nvarchar(max).

Comment: @Henry, perhaps this [ADO.NET C# tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson03) will help. See "Inserting Data."

Comment: @Henry, a sample `insert` statement: `insert into CSV_TABLE (ID, CSV_TEXT) values (12345, "csv,row,one\ncsv,row,two\ncsv,row,three");`.

Comment: @Henry, a table to match the `insert` statement: `create table CSV_TABLE (ID numeric, CSV_TEXT nvarchar(MAX));`.

Comment: Hi DavidRR , my csv file contains more than 10000 records.

Answer (score 1):

You have another helpful C# sample for import and export of CSV file with SQL Server. Below is the link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data import wizard I believe and point it at a csv file. This should create a table that matches the structure of your imported csv